# SharePoint Online CSOM Authentication Code does not working on Sandbox solution

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online, office-365, client-object-model

i need to customize public site and used custom login page for authenticated SharePoint Users.

i am follow below post :

http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/p/57156/207461.aspx#207461

and checked that we can accomplish authenticated using CSOM.  so i have used below code.

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cjohnson/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model)

here is code :

```
        string cmdSpoSite = "https://sharepoint-public.sharepoint.com/";
        string cmdUserName = "username@sharepointahm.onmicrosoft.com";
        string cmdPassword = "password";

        helper = new MsOnlineClaimsHelper(
                    cmdUserName,
                    cmdPassword,
                    cmdSpoSite);

        using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(cmdSpoSite))
        {
            ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += new EventHandler<WebRequestEventArgs>(ctx_ExecutingWebRequest);

            if (ctx != null)
            {
                ctx.Load(ctx.Web); // Query for Web
                ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // Execute

                lbltext.Text = ctx.Web.Title;
                //Console.WriteLine(ctx.Web.Title);
            }
        }
```

`code is worked fine in console app`. when moved on webpart of `Sandbox solution it does not worked`. but when i have used code on webpart `in Farm Solution getting worked fine`.

please guide we can used it or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in a sandbox solution no. You could however create the app running on a separate web server / app and call it in a iframe since it's client object model.

The reason it won't work is because the namespaces you require are blocked in sandbox.

Comment: sound like create asmx service or wcf service to accomplish this.Am i right?

Comment: You don't need to, you can create a new web app for a basic asp.net site and use that for hosting apps. Really this would be a seperate server ideally. Then you can run your csom from there and have it come in a iframe on the page. The use has total transparency as to what is going on. Going forward this is a step towards the 2013 app model which is replacing sandbox.